# knockout select optionText foreach

Tags: knockout.js

I have an object that has a school list with nested classes and nested students in each class

What i need is to bind the optionsText to show the hierarchy so that the dropdown menu shows the options just like :

> School A has
>
> > Student 1
> >
> > Student 2
>
> School B has
>
> > Student 4
> >
> > Student 5
> >
> > Student 6

I am able to get the name of the school on the dropdown but the student part which i am able to get with a foreach on the classes shows as 'undefined' with the binding below.

```
<select data-bind="options: SchoolList, optionsText: function (item) { return item.School + '|' + item.Classes.forEach(function (item) { return item.Student})}, optionsValue: 'Id', value:SchoolListId, optionsCaption: 'Select'" id="school" name="school" class="school"></select>
```

Any help will be appretiated,

Comment: Perhaps this works:  `optionsText: function (item) { return item.School ()  + '|' +  $.map(item.Classes(), function(val,index) {  return val.Student()}).join(', ');    }`

Comment: thank you for your help. i have tried it but it keep return in null. in any case I have learned about the .map and that is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it sounds like you're trying to solve too many things with one dropdown. Perhaps this is more a UX problem than anything. Also, to my knowledge, you cannot invoke that kind of logic in the `optionsText` binding (and why would you?).

What I believe you need is a two step form, OR, a wizard of sorts.

I'll try and "pseudo"-code option 1 below:

```
function Student(){
    var self = this;

    //the properties
};

function School(name, students){
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable();
    self.students = ko.observableArray();

    if(name)
        self.name(name);

    if(students)
        self.students(students);
};

function ViewModel(){
    var self = this;

    self.schools = ko.observableArray(
        new School('A', [
            new Student(),
            new Student(),
        ]),
        new School('A', [
            new Student(),
            new Student(),
            new Student(),
        ]),
    );
};
```

And the markup:

```
<select data-bind="options: schools, value: selectedSchool, valueAllowUnset: false"></select>

<!-- ko if: students().length > 0 -->
    <select data-bind="options: students, value: selectedStudent, valueAllowUnset: false"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct this was the request of the client. You have cleared it up for me. I will use your idea to change the UI and present it to the client. 

The option only takes a string and even though there are custom options out there it would take a bit of effort to implement. I have voted for your answer but since i am new this does not show. Thank you very much.

Comment: @yvanstack not a problem -- wouldn't mind the upvote and correct marker if you wouldn't mind :)

Comment: i will upvote but i have not reputation yet. i will as soon as i get some :) thanks